# My image slide continues incrementing after the last index in my images array

Tags: javascript, html

```
var i = 0;
var tm = 5000;
var images = []; 
images[0] = "img1.png"
images[1] = "img2.png"
images[2] = "img3.png"
function imageslide() {
  document.myslide.src =
    images[i]
  if (i < images.length) {
    i++
  } else { i = 0 }
  setTimeout("imageslide()", tm)
}
window.onload = imageslide;
```

Comment: your condition`i < images.length` allows `i` to be incremented out of bounds it should be `i < images.length - 1`. Otherwise you can simply use the [remainder operator (%)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Remainder) to always keep it in bounds `i = (i+1) % images.length` (though the syntax of your `setTimeout` isn't valid either)

Comment: Sir your suggestion removes the image with the index of 1 from the array there by making it not to show at all